# Hosting WCF service in LAN

Tags: c#, wcf, service, .net-4.0, lan

I have got WCF service allowing sending messages between several users in LAN - sth like chat.
How should I host it? Any recommandations?
This service just should be enabled all the time
I think about Console Application but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of good options. As Alexander said - IIS is one. But it depends on what you want to do with it.

Is there some kind of Server-App you start and interact with then just host the service in there.

But for me the best option is usually to host it inside a simple Windows-Service.
For this I write all that is needed in a seperate assembly and use a console-app during my testing and finally just plug the components inside a simple windows-serivce project and install/run it on some server. No need to have IIS running this way.

Here you can see how the windows-service is done: [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Comment: After reading msdn article, especially:

"This hosting option also makes it easy for rich client applications, such as WPF and WinForms applications, to communicate with the outside world. For example, a peer-to-peer collaboration client that uses WPF for its user interface and also hosts a WCF service that allows other clients to connect to it and share information." I think Console App is the best solution because I have got also clients with WPF application. 

But your proposition about testing in one and hosting finally in another seems interesting. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to be up all the time, and works in a LAN environment, I would recommend:

- a **Windows Service** that runs on some machine
- using the `netTcpBinding` to get the best speed possible

There's really no need to put this into IIS - a Windows Service which runs around the clock works like a charm!

See [MSDN How-To: Host a WCF Service in a Managed application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) for more detailed advice

Answer (score 0):

If it is WCF service, you should host it as WCF service, namely as IIS application.

Here is good screencast of that:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX8quq7MoeI

Answer (score 0):

For intranet scenarios the hosting reccomne recommendation is to use the following decision flowchart, according to Juval Lowy:
[image: WCF Host Decision flowchart]

Also for regarding the decision to use a windows service or a console application: using a windows service as a host is preferable whenere that is posible.

The hosting options are also described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx), and there's a table with advantages and dissadvantage3s of each hosting option, which can help you decide.